# Exchange 2010 Room Calendar conflicts

Tags: exchange, outlook, mailbox

we are having an issue where our conference rooms are allowing meetings that start at the same time. We do have the room auto allow, "Allow conflicting meeting requests" is unchecked, "Conflict percentage allowed" is set to 0, "Maximum conflict instances" is set to 0. So I'm at a loss and all my googling says to check those settings.

[image]

Comment: What are your settings on the "Resource Out-of-Policy Requests" tab?

Comment: It has "Selected Recipients" with nobody added.

Comment: Please run the following command and post the result, it will provide more clues to help troubleshoot this issue:

Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity RoomName |fl

Answer (score 0):

Also try to use the command to enable & disable "Allow conflicting" settings and check again:
Enable it first:

```
Set-CalendarProcessing RoomName -AllowConflict $true
```

Then disable it:

```
Set-CalendarProcessing RoomName -AllowConflict $false -AutomateProcessing AutoAccept
```